Прошивка через JTAG
Пытаюсь прошить через OpenOCD и ft232h в Zywall usg1100 новый U-Boot, пишу halt, затем load_image u-boot-octeon_ebb6300.bin 0x1f800000 bin, шьется долго, и потом при проверке оказывается, что ничего не прошилось. Ладно, делаю по другому, пытаюсь прописать flash init, в ответ оно мне пишет что надо прописать init, пишу, и оно всё равно требует init. При попытке прописать reset init останавливается 0 ядро, а остальные пишут:

TARGET: cpu.core1 - Not halted

или

Halt timed out, wake up GDB.

Пытаюсь в ручную остановить остальные ядра и оно выдает:

Failed to enter Debug Mode!

так же flash bank тоже требует init. Что я делаю не так?

В U-Boot не существует встроенной команды load_image. Вам бы вначале разобраться в окружении, что там накодировано. printenv должен всё показать.

Все вышеприведенные комманды это из openocd, ни одной комманды u-boot нету, и к тому же у меня нет доступа к полноценной консоли юбута, только через местные at комманды коих не так много

Понятно, тут я вам не помощник :( Гуглите...
